# write a Query List Comprehensions for a mnesia query

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension, mnesia

I'm trying to build a small testing app with erlang+mnesia.

I have a user table build from the #user record, as defined here:

```
-record(user_details, {name, password}).
-record(user, {id, details}).
```

then I insert a user with that function:

```
add_sample_data() ->
    Mat = #user{
      details = #user_details{
    name = "mat", password = "mat"
       }
     }, 
    user:insert_user(Mat),
```

the query `[U#user.details || U <- mnesia:table(user)]` return a non empty list.
now I'm trying to build a query which would return a list containing zero record if there is no record with details.name matching Name or the matching record if there is one.

here is the method I use (this one works):

```
user_exists() ->
  Fun = fun() ->
    Query = qlc:q([
      U#user.details || 
      U <- mnesia:table(user)
    ]),
    qlc:e(Query)
  end,
  case mnesia:transaction(Fun) of
    {atomic, []} -> false;
    {atomic, [_User]} -> true
  end.
```

I copied some stuff from [this tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20492533/Erlang-Data-Storage-Modules). A similar problem is solved with `mnesia:select` in the `mne_fun_query({sport, Sport})` method (slide 19) but now I'd like to do it with qlc.

I tried various combinations but without any success (often failed at compilation time..).

I'm really new to erlang, if you can tell which query should works and explains it a little, that would be greatly appreciated!

mat.

**edit**

here is one version which does not work but maybe explain my problem better

```
user_exists() ->
  Fun = fun() ->
    Query = qlc:q([
      U#user.details || 
      U <- mnesia:table(user), 
      U#user.details.name == "mat"     <<<<< This is the line with the problem
    ]),
    qlc:e(Query)
  end,
  case mnesia:transaction(Fun) of
    {atomic, []} -> false;
    {atomic, [_User]} -> true
  end.
```

and the error I have:

> mathieu@evangeneer:~/projects/nopair$ make
>   Recompile: src/resources/user_resource
>   src/resources/user_resource.erl:22: syntax error before: '.'
>   src/resources/user_resource.erl:6: function user_exists/2 undefined make:
>   *** [erl] Error 1

Comment: If it failed at compilation time, paste here the list of errors and warnings. It will make diagnosis easier :)

Comment: one exemple of failed compilation added

Comment: Maybe I can't see things correctly, but you're using `mnesia:transaction(Fun) of ... end` rather than `case mnesia:transaction(Fun) of ... end`. Could that be it?

Comment: I just to much stuff (fixed), I added an indication to tell which line is failing, without it (as in the first example), it compiling and working great. but it return all record of the table (obviously as there is no constraint)

Comment: where to write and run these quries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the problem line:

```
U#user.details.name == "mat"
```

You are attempting to access the `user_details` record but not naming it.  Try...

```
(U#user.details)#user_details.name == "mat"
```

From my experience, the compiler doesn't figure out on its own that #user.details is a #user_details.

Comment: that was it! I tried >a lot< of alternatives with or without #user_details but I didn't find the right one, thx you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common reason QLC code wouldn't compile is if you've left out the header file you're required to include in modules containing qlc queries. Try adding the following to your module and see if it fixes the problem:

```
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").
```

Comment: qlc.hrl is included.  
QLC code works for some (copied & pasted & adapted) query but I can't understand how to write the one I have in mind